# Search Result source : conversation in sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2013

i need a console application where in i need to search the Converation result source( Sharepoint 2013) by passign a set of words and log the content in a table.

Requirement : console app in C# for sharepoint 2013 , which will run everyday, pass the a query string with words eg : microsoft;sharepoint etc . This query string should search against the result source (only for conversation) beacuse we need to monitor the content on teh team sites, mysite and coimmunity site. thos should then put it on teh table with the details which has thes set of words.

please let me know the API's for the same.

Comment: Please can anybody respond,,,

Answer (score 0):

Two ways i found so far, i have a similar scenario:
1. CSOM, but you'll need to get the result source id first and put it in your query:
 var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);

```
                keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResultSourceId"]);

                keywordQuery.QueryText = q;
                keywordQuery.RowLimit = 10;
                keywordQuery.Culture = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LCID"]);

                var searchExec = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

                //var Results = searchExec.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                var r = keywordQuery.GetQuerySuggestionsWithResults(9, 9, true, true, true, true);

                stopwatch.Restart();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                stopwatch.Stop();
```

1. Server Side Object Model, in this way you'll need to run your app in your SharePoint server, and you can get the result source code via code directly:
   var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
                   var ssap = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;

   ```
                   var webOwner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.SPWeb, spWeb);
                   var webResultSource = ssap.GetResultSourceByName(resultSourceName, webOwner);
   ```

The similar to CSOM, you can query your results.